# Understanding the calculation higher order derivative (matrices)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, definition

In *Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems* by Lawrence Perko, higher-order derivatives are defined in the following way,

> Let $E$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then for $(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})$, we have $D^2\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}_0): E \times E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is \begin{equation} D^2\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}_0)(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}) = \sum_{j_1,j_2=1}^n \frac{\partial^2\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}_0)}{\partial x_{j_1} \partial x_{j_2}}x_{j_1}y_{j_2}\label{eq:1}\end{equation}

Here is an example given,

> Let $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}) = \begin{bmatrix}
> x_1 + x_1x_2^2 \newline 
> -x_2 + x_2^2 + x_1^2
> \end{bmatrix}$. Then, $D^2\mathbf{f}(0,1)(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})= \begin{bmatrix}
> 2x_1y_2 + 2x_2y_1 \newline 
> 2x_1y_1 + 2x_2y_2
> \end{bmatrix}$.

I am having trouble understanding how to obtain this result from the given definition. I am presuming the sum in the definition gives the $j_1$ row and $j_2$ column entry. But shouldn't we get a $2 \times 2$ matrix in the example if that was the case?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your function is vector valued, it has two components $f=(f_1,f_2)$. Your second differential will have two components as well.
$D^2f$ is a function of the base point $(x_1,x_2)$ and the increments $(h_1,h_2)$, quadratic in the latter. The notation used in this book is a bit confusing. I would rather write (for a function of two variables)
$$
D^2f(x_1,x_2)(h_1,h_2)=\sum_{i,j}\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}h_ih_j
$$
In your case, the Hessian matrix of $f_1$ is
$$
H_1=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0\quad &2x_2\\
2x_2\quad &2x_1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and therefore
$$
H_1(0,1)=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0\quad &2\\
2\quad &0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and then
$$
D^2f_1(0,1)(h_1,h_2)=2h_1h_2+2h_2h_1.
$$

That is what the first component in your answer means. Same for the second component. BTW, I think there is a typo in the second component of $f$.

Comment: Yes, there is a typo (just checked Perko's book): the second component of $f$ should be $-x_2+x_2^2+x_1^2$.